# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, macos, docker

I have created this java application using spring boot on IDE IntelliJ
following are my configuration files. Application builds successfully but I get this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

worked around this,
added jar to classpath but didn't work

application.properties

```
# port
server.port=7031

# ms sql database
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://0.0.0.0:1433;databaseName=PEOPLEHUM
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=mssql@123
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

spring.batch.job.enabled=false

# cron value for executor
scheduled.job.attendance.logs.cron=0 0 0/12 ? * *

# Logging pattern for file
logging.pattern.file= %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%

# output to a C:/peoplehum/logs/
logging.path=C:/peoplehum/logs/
logging.file=C:/peoplehum/logs/logs.log
logging.file.max-size=10MB
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.0.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.peoplehum'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    runtimeOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    compile group: 'net.sf.ucanaccess', name: 'ucanaccess', version: '4.0.4'
    compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.2.4'
    compile group: 'com.squareup.okhttp', name: 'okhttp', version: '2.3.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.6'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.12.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.12.1'
    testCompile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'sqljdbc4', version: '4.0'

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

bootJar {
    launchScript()
}
```

I have gone through many solutions available on web but nothing worked for me

After Zakir's suggestion I updated my driver dependency following error is still coming:
sorry, already tried

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/devtools/autoconfigure/DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Comment: Check if the version of your jar package matches the version of your database

Comment: Shouldn't the driver class name be set to `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` in your properties? Right now it is `com`.

Comment: @bpzhang
database installed in docker :
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU13) (KB4466404) - 14.0.3048.4 (X64)
 Nov 30 2018 12:57:58
 Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS)
jar using :
testCompile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '6.2.2.jre8'

Comment: @michalk I updated sorry please review, still not working

Comment: just to remind everyone, I am using dockerized mssql 2017

Answer (score 1):

Use the updated jar and change the gradle dependency as below :

```
testCompile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '6.1.0.jre7'
```

source: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/6.1.0.jre7

Comment: After seeing your updated error, you can do 2 things to fix it 

1. `<scope>runtime</scope>` you should not have this in your sqlserver driver depedency

2.if you are not in need of data source then remove it from autoconfig process:
`@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})`

Comment: I am using gradle and don't have runtime there you can see that it in build.gradle up there, Second since I am connecting to the database, why should I include second option. After adding it will I be able to use database?